# How to show and hide div tag in Index.csthml in ASP.NET C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I have a bool in my ViewModel.cs

```
public bool HasPackType { get; set; }
```

### Summary & Question

So the idea is simple, if HasPackType is true, hide the div tag in Index.cshtml.

I know there are many ways to hide stuff in index.cshtml, but for this particular situation, to keep it simple, I would like to hide the div without JavaScript code.

I have tried this:

```
  <div class="form-group spaced" style=@(Model.HasPackType;) "display: none;">
                            
   </div>
```

Still cannot hide the div when my program is running so I wonder if I am thinking "right" with this solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you don't want use JS, this code solve your problem.

```
     <div class="form-group spaced" style="@(Model.HasPackType ? "display: none;" : "" )" >
                             
     </div>
```

and if you don't want Generate html you can use this:

```
@if (!Model.HasPackType){
    <div class="form-group spaced">
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem you've got is that you're not generating valid HTML and could probably use the ternary operator

```
<div class="form-group spaced" style="@{ Model.HasPackType ? "display: none;" : string.Empty }">
</div>
```

This way you're free to unhide it in JavaScript later.

However, if you don't even want the div in the markup at all you could wrap it with an `@if`

```
@if (!Model.HasPackType){
    <div class="form-group spaced">
    </div>
}
```